# Drawing similar picture with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot, technical-drawing, tikz-graphdrawing, tikz-shape

Is it possible to make something like this in tikz? 
How to? :)

f(t) can be literally any curve, this arrow pointing it is just a comment, not a part of a drawing

[image: graph1]

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) it should be doable, but this site is not a _do this for me_ service, so please show what you have so far.

Comment: @daleif so far i can draw this in 2D, adding another dimension overwhelms me

Comment: @user464980, than show this, please!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! As @daleif says, this is not a TeXing service. However, as you are a newcomer, here's a starting point.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{30}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,>=latex,line join=bevel]
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
    \draw[thick,->] (O) -- (0,0,8) node[anchor=east]{$z$};
    \draw plot[variable=\x,domain=0:360,samples=101,smooth] ({2+sin(\x)},{1.5-cos(\x)},{\x/60});
    \foreach \Z in {0,3,6}
    {\draw (0,0,\Z) -- (4,0,\Z) node[midway,below]{$x$} 
    -- (4,3,\Z) node[midway,below right]{$y$} -- (0,3,\Z) -- cycle; } 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]